# Data share between native android and html

Tags: android

I have basic html web page and in that web page I'm trying to invoke a native android application. I tried that and it is working fine. NOw I need to share some data from natvie application to html  without  webview. is it possible.

Can anyone provide me any suggestions or solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

hmm you can do this by first reading the whole html page in InputStream. then replacing the desired strings with your data from the android application.